# Adding expire functionality to python-rom objects

Tags: python, redis

I am working with flask and redis. I've using the rom redis orm (http://pythonhosted.org/rom/) to manage some mildly complex data structures. I want to add the ability to set the objects to set an expiry time.

Based on https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom/issues/40 and https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom/pull/47

I have a rom model:

```
class A(rom.Model):
    url = rom.String(required=True, unique=True)()
    t = rom.String()
    delete_at = rom.Float(index=True)
    created_at = rom.Float(default=time.time, index=True)
```

which I can instantiate and save:

```
a_object = A(url=u, delete_at =time.time+7200) # 2 hour expiry
try:
    ad_object.save()
except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
```

I have a cronjob which executes every hour and so I want to do something like:

```
 delete_list = A.get_by((time.time()-delete_at>0)) # pseudocode.
```

Obviously this is incorrect, but if I can get this into a list I could delete these. How can I express the above pseudocode using the rom ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed Josiah, the package developer. His answer:

```
"This can be done in one of 2 ways:

delete_list = A.get_by(delete_at=(0, time.time()))
delete_list = A.query.filter(delete_at=(0, time.time())).all()

The query attribute/object offers a collection of different filers, depending on your defined indexes."
```